# Expectation of $XX.T$ vs Expectation of X * Expectation of X.T

Tags: random-matrices

I need to understand what follows:

Given

- $X \in \mathbb{R}^{T \times n_0}$
- $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n_0 \times n} : W_{ij}\sim \mathbb{N(0, \frac{1}{n_0})} \space i.i.d.$
- $\sigma : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ so that $\sigma(x) = max(0,x)$
- $S = \sigma(XW)$ where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is applied element-wise

lets define the matrices

- $K = \mathbb{E}_W[S^{}S^{T}]$
- $H = \mathbb{E}_W[S]^{}\mathbb{E}_W[S]^{T}$

In general $K$ and $H$ are different. Anyway, what is the relationship between the matrices $K$ and $H$ ?

To me this question is related to the "expectation of variance VS variance of expectation" topic, but in this case there are two main differences: random matrices are involved and I'm considering $S^{}S^{T}$ istead of $S^{T}S^{}$.

(Optional: can you give me some references where these topics are explained at the beginner level).

Comment: What is the relation between $E(X^2)$  and $E(X)^2$?

Comment: @Redshoes The only formula I know that contains both of them is the one involving the variance $Var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2$, but it is still true when we consider random matrices?

Comment: I would say $K-H = Cov(SS^T)$.